# PHP Echo Overwrite

Tags: php, echo

I am working on a program in which information from a form is reprinted using an echo command.  I had hoped for the user to be able to create a list by typing into the form, clicking submit, printing this to the screen, repeat.  However, every time I click submit, the previously printed text is removed and printed over.  How can I force it to print to the next line and not delete the previous lines.  I am using:

```
echo $_POST['Field'];
```

Comment: Post your code and someone will try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid using the server's memory for saving the previous lines, you could use a hidden field.

Try something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="txtCurrentLine" />
<input type="hidden" name="hdnPreviousLines" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['hdnPreviousLines'] . '<br />' . $_POST['txtCurrentLine']); ?>" />
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
```

```
You have entered: <br /><?php echo htmlentities($_POST['hdnPreviousLines'] . '<br />' . $_POST['txtCurrentLine']); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use session or cookie to save previously lines. for example:

```
$_SESSION['all_lines'].=$_POST['Field']."<br/>";
echo $_SESSION['all_lines'];
```